# Get Current State of an ATN

Tags: antlr4

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the current ATNState? I am implementing ParseTreeListener directly and would like to do something along these lines:

```
public class MyParseTreeListener implements ParseTreeListener {

    private ATN atn;

    public MyParseTreeListener(ATN atn) {
        this.atn = atn;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode terminalNode) {
        // atn.getCurrentState();
    }
}
```

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information isn't preserved in the parse tree by default. You'll need to do the following to preserve it.

1. Create a new class that extends `TerminalNodeImpl` and has a new field for storing the `ATNState` (I assume you are interested in the `ATNState` which contains an outgoing match transition for the terminal).
2. Override the `Parser.consume()` method and duplicate its contents. Replace the call to `ParserRuleContext.addChild(Token)` with code that creates an instance of your custom terminal node and adds it to the tree using `ParserRuleContext.addChild(TerminalNode)`. Make sure to set the `parent` field of your custom terminal node since `ParserRuleContext.addChild(TerminalNode)` won't do it for you.